# Sphinx search - multiple counts

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I have a list of items with albums & images and I want to display them like this:

Item 1 (3 albums, 10 images)

Item 2 (2 albums, 5 images)

I can use group by albums or images but for the second one i need to make an extra query.

So, exists another posibility to hold both counts in the same query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index your albums and images count into Item table. It will be faster to display them and you wont loose data if you create triggers for those tables.

And then you can index those fields with sphinx.